# Define method from external module (Python)

Tags: python, class, methods, module

I'm trying to define a method (let's call it `hello`) in `main.py`'s `Things` class, from `define.py`.

The code I currently have is raising `AttributeError: module 'runme' has no attribute 'promptMe'` (full traceback below).

**Here's `main.py`'s code:**

```
import define

class Things:
    def doWhatever():
        print("whatever")
```

**Here's `define.py`'s code:**

```
import main

def hello():
    print("Hello!")

main.Things.hello = hello()
```

I've tried other solutions such as `def main.Things.hello: hello()` and `def main.Things.hello: print("Hello!")` but none work.

**Here's the traceback when running `define.py`:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "define.py", line 5, in <module>
    import main
  File "/path/to/main.py", line 9, in <module>
    import define
  File "/path/to/define.py", line 10, in <module>
    main.Things.hello = hello
AttributeError: module 'main' has no attribute 'Things'
```

All help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Running from `main.py` doesn't work either - I'll add a traceback soon.

Comment: Avoid circular import.

Comment: @falsetru Then how do I do this without it? I need `define.py` to know what to define, and I need `main.py` to know that `Things` has been changed.

Comment: Sounds like you need to restructure this, then. FWIW, `main` is not globally updated. Only the imported version is. If different files import `main`, the change doesn't propagate to all of them.

Comment: @aryamccarthy Would it be possible to do something like this in `main.py`? `Things.hello() = hello.hello()`?

Comment: It would be `Things.hello = main.hello` (no parentheses), but yeah.

Comment: Oops - I meant `Things.hello = define.hello`

Comment: Circular import. Restructure your code to have a common module for both of define and main to import from instead.